# What happens when a neutrino and antineutrino meet?

Tags: neutrinos, antimatter

My minimal knowledge of matter/animatter interaction is that only light is released and they obliviate each other.
is this the same for neutrinos?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127502/123208

Comment: From 1986: [Neutrino-antineutrino annihilation around a collapsar](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1987A%26A...175..309B/0000309.000.html)

Comment: Also related, kind of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/549859/123208

Comment: So basically this is not unknown science? Surely somewhere there a Feynman diagram. I cant find it.

Comment: Justin, there *might* be Feynman diagrams here: [The annihilation of a neutrino-anti-neutrino pair into photons and the neutrino density in the universe](https://doi.org/10.1016/0029-5582(66)90233-1), but it's paywalled. There's an approximate cross section formula in the abstract, but I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring , that abstract sort of answers a lot really.

Comment: Related Physics SE question: ["What is the product of low energy neutrino annihilation?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208539/145491)

Answer (score -1):

Matter-antimatter annihilations don't need to only turn into "light" (or more precisely "photons"), however that is what happens with electron/positron annihilation which is to my knowledge the most common antimatter interaction in the real world.

Neutrino-antineutrino annihilation is extremely rare because they're both scarcely interactive and scarcely abundant. Since the neutrino is coupled to the weak force and the EM force, I believe that neutrino-antineutrino annhiliation can produce photons or Z bosons/mesons (all with varying probabilities). Incidentally, anything that can decay into a antineutrino-neutrino pair (which a photon I believe) can be a product of their annihilation, as QFT is reversible. My certainty on this is not 100% so I'm happy to be corrected by someone better versed in the specifics.

Comment: "scarcely abundant" that bit isn't quite right. On earth the neutrino flux, just from our sun, is about 65billion per square centimeter per second (on a surface with normal towards the sun). Even intergalactic space is believed to have quite a high density.

Comment: Neutrinos are neutral, they don't couple to the EM force.

Comment: @Triatticus photons are neutral

Comment: @SeñorO which is why EM is linear: photons don't couple to photons.

Comment: There are vast numbers of neutrinos (& antineutrinos) in the [cosmic neutrino background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background), a relic from the Big Bang, but due to their *extremely* low energy, they barely interact with anything.

Comment: As I now understand it. Photons are not the only bosons that represent pure energy in this context. A z-boson can suffice or for that matter any boson. Am I right?